# Ubuntu installation USB never finishes loading

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I was trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 onto my HP 250G7 i3 10th gen laptop. It has a UEFI BIOS. I am using a bootable flash-drive but the loading wheel screen stays up continuously and does not stop loading. The same ISO image installed perfectly fine in a virtual machine. It is only happening with Ubuntu because when I tried Linux Mint, it installed successfully.

[image: UEFI loading screen]

Comment: How did you create the USB drive, which tool or method did you use? What graphics chip/card is there in the computer?

Comment: I used ventoy-1.0.70 to make a bootable flash-drive and my graphics card is intel UHD G1 (integrated GPU).

Comment: Ventoy and Intel graphics have a good reputation [to cooperate well with Ubuntu]. - If you want to some experimenting, I suggest that you try to extract and clone Ubuntu Server from a compressed image file into the USB drive (could be a pendrive or SSD). The server has a simple text mode interface and should be easier to get working. If it works, the next step would be to install a graphical desktop system into it, standard Ubuntu or maybe a lightweight community flavour (for example Lubuntu or Xubuntu) ...

Comment: ... See the description at [this link to a thread at the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). Maybe Ventoy is *not* the right tool to install from  a compressed image file into the USB drive, but I know that [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) in Windows and [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Ubuntu works.